# Cordova fingerprint authentication on server

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fingerprint

I am trying to create a authentication mechanism in my (cordova) app for android that will allow my users to sign in using a password and username, or allow them to scan their finger in order to sign in.

How can one verify a fingerprint registered on a client, server side? is this even possible at all using Cordova ? I tried transmitting the result of a finger scan to my server: this looked like:

```
FingerprintAuth.isAvailable(function(result) {
  if (result.isAvailable) {
    if(result.hasEnrolledFingerprints){
      FingerprintAuth.show({
        clientId: client_id,
        clientSecret: client_secret
      }, function (result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));

        $http.post('http://192.168.149.33:3000/authorize', result).then(
          function(response) {}
        );

        if (result.withFingerprint) {
          $scope.$parent.loggedIn = true;
          alert("Successfully authenticated using a fingerprint");
          $location.path( "/home" );
        } else if (result.withPassword) {
          alert("Authenticated with backup password");
        }
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error); // "Fingerprint authentication not available"
      });
    } else {
      alert("Fingerprint auth available, but no fingerprint registered on the device");
    }
  }
}, function(message) {
  alert("Cannot detect fingerprint device : "+ message);
});
```

Server side i am receiving the following data (3 seperate scans):

```
{ withFingerprint: 't8haYq36fmBPUEPbVjiWOaBLjMPBeUNP/BTOkoVtZ2ZiX20eBVzZAs3dn6PW/R4E\n' }
{ withFingerprint: 'rA9H+MIoQR3au9pqgLAi/EOCRA9b0Wx1AvzC/taGIUc8cCeDfzfiDZkxNy5U4joB\n' }
{ withFingerprint: 'MMyJm46O8MTxsa9aofKUS9fZW3OZVG7ojD+XspO71LWVy4TZh2FtvPtfjJFnj7Sy\n' }
```

The patterns seems to vary every time,  is there a way one can link the finger print to for example a pattern saved under a user on a database ?

Comment: I believe plugins should be the way to go for such implementations. Please check out this plugin - https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

Comment: Hi mark  I have a doubt?. How to get the clientid and client_secret?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P I think you will have to dive in to native code for that. Or you could search for a cordova plugin wich interfaces that that native functionality.

Comment: @Gandhi- I have already used above plugin but in which format we have to store fingerprint in db like.string or any image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer**

The strings returned by this API are not "fingerprint patterns". So you won't be able to authenticate the way you're thinking...

**Long answer**

Let's start by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth) of the API it looks like you're using.

Looking at [this file](https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth/blob/master/src/android/FingerprintAuth.java) we see these methods:

```
public static void onAuthenticated(boolean withFingerprint) {
    JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
    String errorMessage = "";
    boolean createdResultJson = false;
    try {

        if (withFingerprint) {
            // If the user has authenticated with fingerprint, verify that using cryptography and
            // then return the encrypted token
            byte[] encrypted = tryEncrypt();
            resultJson.put("withFingerprint", Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, 0 /* flags */));
        } else {
            // Authentication happened with backup password.
            resultJson.put("withPassword", true);

            // if failed to init cipher because of InvalidKeyException, create new key
            if (!initCipher()) {
                createKey();
            }
        }
        createdResultJson = true;

// ...

/**
 * Tries to encrypt some data with the generated key in {@link #createKey} which is
 * only works if the user has just authenticated via fingerprint.
 */
private static byte[] tryEncrypt() throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    return mCipher.doFinal(mClientSecret.getBytes());
}
```

Look at what's being put to `"withFingerprint"`. It's a Base64 encoding of the encrypted client secret. Technically, this *is* your authentication. You would use this token to authenticate requests and your server would decrypt and validate the client secret.

**Summary**

Fingerprinting adds a level of security, but it is not the only means of security. A relationship needs to be established with the device and server beforehand.

I found this diagram to be helpful in understanding the intent of android's fingerprint authentication (ref: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Comment: @MarkStroeven no problem! I learned a bit about fingerprinting too :)

Comment: useful information. Thanks. just adding link of android blog for the above diagram: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't authenticate fingerprint on the server, fingerprints are stored or authenticated using `Live Scan/Biometric template`. Authentication is done by comparing the current scan template with previously stored templates

First of all you  don't have access to these stored templates(Not provided by the OS providers/Phone Manufacturers) and If we assume that you have access  to those templates, then an efficient algorithm (Image based /Pattern based ) is required to compare the current template with previously stored templates. You can't simply authenticate it by string comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Use cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio for fingerprint authentication .

For further info you can consult https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio .